# JavaScript regex to accept numbers with comma separator (thousands) and dot separator (decimals)

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, dart, range

Could any of you help me with a regular expression which will accept these:

For every thousand a comma will be accepted.
No less than 4 decimal points in number

I've been testing this pattern but fails in some scenarios:

```
^\d+(\,\d+{1.3} \.d{1.4})*$
```

Valid inputs:

```
1
11
111
1,111
1,111,111
1.1111
11.1111
111.1111
1,111.1111
```

Invalid inputs:

```
Any letter
1,1
1.1
1.11
1,11.11
1,111.1
```

The main criterions are:
(4 decimal points are obligatory).
(3 numbers per thousand must have a comma.)

Comment: Did you search before you asked?  --> related questions to the right has answers you should try.

Comment: This is not clear: `1.1`, `1.11` and `1,111.1` seem valid. *No more than 4 decimal points in number* means there can be 1 to 4. However, at the bottom, you write *4 decimal points are obligatory*. If the last statement is correct, you need `^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{4})?$` or `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{4})?$`

Comment: Thanks for noticing Wiktor, i just edited the message, should be no less than 4 decimal points.

Comment: Try `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{4,})?$` then. Or `^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{4,})?$` if `12334455767` like numbers must be also matched.

Comment: A number cannot have 4 decimal points: one at the most. I suppose you mean decimal digits. But then you also probably mean: either no decimal digits at all, or at least 4 of them.

Comment: Stick your regexp into a regexp tester and play with it and tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more complicated than

```
/^\d\d?\d?(,\d\d\d)*(\.\d\d\d\d)?$/
```

or if you prefer

```
/^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{4})?$/
```

Comment: I actually [suggested that already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918783/javascript-regex-to-accept-numbers-with-comma-separator-thousands-and-dot-sepa#comment65194428_38918783) and OP did not confirm it is working.